# file type value as image source

Tags: javascript

I have a div on my page which has an image tag and input type as file.
What I want to do is that when I choose the image I get the url in text box besides choose button. I want to give it as path for image source.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function load()
{
    var  path = document.getElementById('image').value;
    var newpath="file:///" + path;
    document.getElementById('image').src = newpath;

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="height:300px; width:300px; border:1px solid red;">
<img id="1" src="load()" height="300" width="300">
</div>
<form action="demo_form.asp">
  Select a file: <input type="file" id="image" onclick="load()" >
                 <input type=submit onclick="load()">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is not possible due to some security concerns.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify a file input's value with code, because it would mean that anyone could force you to send any file that you have on your computer instead of the one you have chosen.

To achieve this, your only way is to hide the text box in the file input and create a new one that you can control.

```
<input id="txtNewPath" type="text" />
```

then

```
function load() {
    var path = document.getElementById('image').value;
    var newpath="file:///" + path;
    document.getElementById('txtNewPath').value = newpath;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in this line:

```
document.getElementById('image').src = newpath;
```

change it to point to the img tag:

```
document.getElementById('1').src = newpath;
```

Comment: No your assumption is wrong.  OP is all about `input type file`

Comment: then return the newpath in the end of load() function.

Comment: I believe what you are facing is a security issue, google "Access local files from browser" I think you will find what you are missing

Comment: is it because fakepath thing

Comment: Fredrik this is not working as it again gives a fakepath which is not accepted as img src   http://jsfiddle.net/yahavbr/gP7Bz/  check thi out

Comment: as I told you this is due some security issues so you can't capture the user file system path, there are some work arounds for this issue if you only want to give the user a preview this can be done using a plugin like: http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/index.html